# What info can be gleaned from Tor traffic over a local network?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security

Or put another way, what does Tor traffic look like when monitored over a home router? Would info like URL/DNS lookups be visible? What would the URLs and packet headers/contents look like?

And if there's a way that I could see this for myself, that would be all the better.

Answer (score 1):

Tor traffic over a local network will look exactly like what it looks like on the outside. There is no URL/DNS info leaked.

You can verify that by yourself by running a packet sniffer on your computer. I recommend [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which is available for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Open WireShark, select the network interface you want to sniff on (Ethernet or Wireless or etc), and then press the green Start button, and it will show you all packets that pass by (in or out) your network card in real time.

You can filter the results by writing *http* or *dns* in the 'filter' field, or from the menu *Capture* -> *Capture filters*. Be aware that if you want to change the filter, you may have to stop the capturing and restart it.